# Нет подключения к серверу Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, mvc, spring-mvc, maven

Начал изучать SpringMVC. Обучение происходило без проблем, но только до первого запуска первого приложения. Почему-то мне пишет, что файл **hello_world** недоступен. Единственное что себе предположил, так это то, что может зависимости в Maven подключил не новые. Прошу помощи, может кто-то уже встречался с таким. Заранее спасибо!

Код

**web**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>spring-mvc-app1</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering/>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContextMVC.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**applicationContextMVC**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.alishev.springcourse"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
        <property name="enableSpringELCompiler" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="viewNames" value="*"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**HelloController**

```
package ru.alishev.springcourse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/hello-world")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "hello_world";
    }
}
```

Вот что мне выбивает, когда подключаюсь к серверу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы пробуете обращаться к ресурсу как к `/hello_world` (судя по ошибке), но он не может его найти, потому как в контроллере вы замапили метод на `/hello-world`

Comment: @azlov, да, все верно. У меня файл называется hello_world.html, и я хочу чтобы когда было введено в адресную строку localhost:8080/hello-world, то мне открывалась именно эта html-страница. И при том, если я даже ничего не маплю, оно бы по идеи должно было открыть стартовую страницу tomcat, но и в этом случае, ошибка та же самая.

Comment: В скрине написано, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к `localhost:8080/hello_world` через нижнее подчеркивание, а `/hello_world`  у вас никак не обрабатывается

Comment: @azlov, но я обращаюсь по адресу localhost:8080/hello-world